# Conflict when using server-side includes and mod_deflate compression

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssi

I'm trying to enable site-wide compression using the apache mod_deflate module. This is on a shared server so whilst I have access to the .htaccess files, I cannot alter the server settings. The server has Apache 2.4.6 installed with mod_deflate

My problem is that by adding the requisite code to my .htaccess, my server side includes are disabled (possibly removed during compression?), or the whole thing just breaks and the site wont load.

My .htaccess code for enabling SSI is

> AddHandler server-parsed .html

I use the following format for implementing SSI's in the HTML

```
<!--#include virtual="/includes/header.html" -->
```

The code I am supposed to add to the .htaccess for compression is:

```
<IfModule filter_module>
FilterDeclare COMPRESS
FilterProvider COMPRESS DEFLATE "%{CONTENT_TYPE} = 'text/html'"
FilterProvider COMPRESS DEFLATE "%{CONTENT_TYPE} = 'text/css'"
FilterProvider COMPRESS DEFLATE "%{CONTENT_TYPE} = 'text/plain'"
FilterProvider COMPRESS DEFLATE "%{CONTENT_TYPE} = 'text/xml'"
FilterProvider COMPRESS DEFLATE "%{CONTENT_TYPE} = 'text/x-component'"
FilterProvider COMPRESS DEFLATE "%{CONTENT_TYPE} = 'application/javascript'"
FilterProvider COMPRESS DEFLATE "%{CONTENT_TYPE} = 'application/json'"
FilterProvider COMPRESS DEFLATE "%{CONTENT_TYPE} = 'application/xml'"
FilterProvider COMPRESS DEFLATE "%{CONTENT_TYPE} = 'application/xhtml+xml'"
FilterProvider COMPRESS DEFLATE "%{CONTENT_TYPE} = 'application/rss+xml'"
FilterProvider COMPRESS DEFLATE "%{CONTENT_TYPE} = 'application/atom+xml'"
FilterProvider COMPRESS DEFLATE "%{CONTENT_TYPE} = 'application/vnd.ms-fontobject'"
FilterProvider COMPRESS DEFLATE "%{CONTENT_TYPE} = 'image/svg+xml'"
FilterProvider COMPRESS DEFLATE "%{CONTENT_TYPE} = 'application/x-font-ttf'"
FilterProvider COMPRESS DEFLATE "%{CONTENT_TYPE} = 'font/opentype'"
FilterProvider COMPRESS DEFLATE "%{CONTENT_TYPE} = 'image/x-icon'"
FilterProvider COMPRESS DEFLATE "%{CONTENT_TYPE} = '/application/(javascript|json|xml|x-javascript)/'"
FilterProvider COMPRESS DEFLATE "%{CONTENT_TYPE} = '/text/(html|css|javascript|plain|x(ml|-component))/'"
FilterChain COMPRESS
FilterProtocol COMPRESS DEFLATE change=yes;byteranges=no
</IfModule>
```

Adding the above causes an entire crash, removing the SSI's allows compression to work, but breaks the includes!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same bug, i downgraded to Apache 2.2.22 and it worked.